# How to customize Wordpress login error message?

Tags: wordpress

I am using the Google apps login plugin to log Google users into my Wordpress website.

When I try to login with a non registered user I get the following error message

```
User foo@bar.com not registered in Wordpress
```

I am not sure if this is a plugin query but how would I go about changing this error message to be

```
User foo@bar.com is not registered
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Hello sir , 

   you can do it by the edit of core file just go in your plugin folder-open google-app-login plugin >core folder->core_google_apps_login.php 
just open this file and and jump on line no 380 and edit the function 





protected function createUserOrError($userinfo, $options) {
        return( new WP_Error('ga_login_error', sprintf( __( 'User %s not registered in Wordpress' , 'google-apps-login'),
                                                 $userinfo->email) ) );
    }




 to :





protected function createUserOrError($userinfo, $options) {
        return( new WP_Error('ga_login_error', sprintf( __( 'User %s not registered' , 'google-apps-login'),
                                                 $userinfo->email) ) );
    }


Try
```